# ¿Por qué es importante sobrrescribir GetHashCode cuando Equals es sobreescrito?

Tags: c#, .net

Suponiendo que tengo la siguiente clase:

```
public class Foo
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public string FooName { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        Foo fooItem = obj as Foo;

        return fooItem.FooId == this.FooId;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
       // ¿Cúal es preferible?
       return base.GetHashCode();
       //return this.FooId.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Sobreescribí el método `Equals` porque `Foo` representa una fila en una tabla de `Foo`s. ¿Cuál es el método correcto para sobreescribir `GetHashCode`?

¿Por qué es importante sobreescribir `GetHashCode`?

Esta es una traducción de la [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/371328/5213794) de [David Basarab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2469/david-basarab)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, es importante si tus objetos serán usados como `key` en un `Dictionary<T>`, `HashSet<T>`, etc, ya que estos se usan (en ausencia de un `IEqualityComparer<T>` personalizado) para agrupar elementos. Si el HashCode para dos objetos no coincide, estos nunca serán considerados iguales (`Equals` simplemente no será llamado).

if the GetHashCode() is equal, it is not necessary for them to be the same; this is a collision, and  Equals will be called to see if it is a real equality or not.

El método `GetHashCode()` deberá reflejar la lógica de `Equals`, las reglas son:

- Si dos objetos son iguales, `(Equals(...) == true)`, entonces ambos **deben** devolver el mismo valor para `GetHashCode()`
- Si el `GetHashCode()` es igual, no necesariamente implica que serán iguales, en este punto, `Equals` será llamado para ver si efectivamente los objetos son iguales o no.

In this case, it looks like "return FooId;" is a suitable GetHashCode() implementation. If you are testing multiple properties, it is common to combine them using code like below, to reduce diagonal collisions (i.e. so that new Foo(3,5) has a different hash-code to new Foo(5,3)):

En este caso, al parecer, `return FooId` es una implementación adecuada para `GetHashCode()`,  Si estás testeando múltiples propiedades, es común combinarlas usando el siguiente código para reducir colisiones (por ejemplo, `new Foo(3,5)` debe tener diferente HashCode que `new Foo(5,3)`

```
unchecked //Solo es necesario si está compilando con los controles aritméticos
{//Por defecto están deshabilitados, así la mayoría de la gente no lo necesitará.
    int hash = 13;
    hash = (hash * 7) + field1.GetHashCode();
    hash = (hash * 7) + field2.GetHashCode();
    ...
    return hash;
}
```

Por conveniencia, también se debe considerar sobreescribir los operadores `==` y `!=` cuando se sobreescribe `Equals` y `GetHashCode`

Esta es una traducción de la [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/371348/5213794) de [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) en StackOverflow en Inglés

Comment: Si alguien nota algún error de traducción, le ruego ayudar editando la respuesta!

Answer (score 1):

Es usado para comparar objetos , por ejemplo:

```
public class Gato
{ 
 public string Nombre {get; set;}
 public string Raza {get; set;}
 public string NombrePoseedor {get; set;}
}
//dos instancias mismas propiedades

var GatoUno= new Gato{Nombre="asrael",Raza="comun", NombrePoseedor="Gargamel"};

var GatoDos= new Gato{Nombre="asrael",Raza="comun" ,NombrePoseedor="Gargamel"};

//declarando una comparacion
Console.WriteLine($"Gatos Iguales? = { GatoUno.Equals(GatoDos) }");
  //Gatos Iguales? = false
```

Esto es aunque tienen las mismas propiedades no son los mismos objetos (cada gato tiene una referencia diferente y eso lo utiliza Equals), para solucionarlo se puede sobreescribir Equals y comparar sus propiedades, solucionado!. Excepto que si agregas ese objeto en un diccionario y lo quieres comparar para saber si existe no se obtiene un true
para el caso de los gatos uno y dos, y se debe a que Dictionary utiliza el Hash para comparar, asi que si desearas saber cual es el hash para los gatos.

se tiene :

```
   var gatosDictionary = new Dictionary<Gatos, int> { { GatoUno, 1 } };
var salida=  gatosDictionary.ContainsKey(GatoDos) ;


Console.WriteLine($"Ya existe? {salida}");
 //false 
Console.WriteLine(GatoUno.GetHashCode()); // 3423423
Console.WriteLine(GatoDos.GetHashCode());  // 465464
```

Entonces suponiendo que para nosotros dos Objetos Gato son iguales simplemente
si pertenecen al mismo dueño y tienen el mismo nombre, en nuetra declaracion del hash
se sobreescribiria :

```
public override int GetHashCode() =>
   new { Nombre, NombrePoseedor }.GetHashCode();
```

Asi si se agrego el GatoUno al diccionario y se quiere saber si existe antes de agregar
el GatoDos

```
var salida=  gatosDictionary.ContainsKey(GatoDos) ;
//salida= true
```

//o si quieres comparar usando su hash

```
Console.WriteLine($"Gatos Iguales? = { GatoUno.GetHashCode()==GatoDos.GetHashCode() }");
  //Gatos Iguales? = true
```

Espero haya quedado claro la rapida explicacion,

Saludos.